# While overriding customer createaccount() apis iam getting below errors magento2 rest api

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I have Overrrided the v1/customers rest api and added in my custom module the method CreateAccount() in my model file
and the file is working fine when checking postman

But while creating a customer it is giving an errors like below

Can you please help me out on this.

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getValue() on null in vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php: 811
Stack trace:
#0 vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php(745): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement->getMinPasswordLength()
#1 app/code/vendor/CustomApi/Model/AccountManagement.php(513): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement->checkPasswordStrength('Password6')
#2 /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Meetanshi/CustomApi/Model/AccountManagement/Interceptor.php(24): Meetanshi\CustomApi\Model\AccountManagement->createAccount(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer), 'Password6', '')
#3 [internal function
]: Meetanshi\CustomApi\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor->createAccount(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer), 'Password6', '')
#4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php on line **811**
{
"messages": {
"error": [
{
"code": 500,
"message": "Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getValue() on null in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php:811\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php(745): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement->getMinPasswordLength()\n#1 /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Meetanshi/CustomApi/Model/AccountManagement.php(513): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement->checkPasswordStrength('Password6')\n#2 /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Meetanshi/CustomApi/Model/AccountManagement/Interceptor.php(24): Meetanshi\CustomApi\Model\AccountManagement->createAccount(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer), 'Password6', '')\n#3 [internal function]: Meetanshi\CustomApi\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor->createAccount(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer), 'Password6', '')\n#4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#5 /var/ww' in '/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php' on line 811",
"trace": "Trace is not available."
}
]
}

Comment: Can you please share your di.xml and your custom code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems in which object you are calling the getValue() having nothing to operate. Just print the data and verify if you have some data to operate.